# Não consigo pegar o value do input "csrfmiddlewaretoken"

Tags: python-3.x

Não consigo pegar o value do input "csrfmiddlewaretoken" deste link, alguém poderia me ajudar ? "O script teria basicamente que visitar a página que está no código e retornar o value do input cujo o name é "csrfmiddlewaretoken" no console

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')



req = r.get('https://www.udemy.com/join/login-popup/?ref=&display_type=popup&locale=pt_BR&response_type=json&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udemy.com%2Fmobile%2Fipad%2F&xref=')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
inp = soup.find('input', {'name': 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'})
val_inp = inp.get('value')
```

Erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gg.py", line 18, in <module>
    val_inp = inp.get('value')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Na página:

```
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='VyHNALqmdrUIRP72n3Yj8O8lsN0vfQwtsmzbCYbuTNDbtLR1sbg2Xk368y7U8M7d' />
```

O value muda a cada request/f5/refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você analisar o retono do request na variável `soup` (com o comando `print(repr(soup))`) verá que o site está retornando a mensagem:

> Access to this page has been denied because we believe you are using automation tools to browse the website.

Ou seja, o site detecta que o request foi feito por uma ferramenta automática e retorna um conteúdo diferente do esperado.

Uma solução possível para este caso é informar o *header* `User-Agent` com o mesmo valor de um browser comum.

Segue o código modificado utilizando o *user agent* do browser FireFox:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')


# AQUI => informar o User-Agent'
req = r.get(
         'https://www.udemy.com/join/login-popup/?ref=&display_type=popup&locale=pt_BR&response_type=json&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udemy.com%2Fmobile%2Fipad%2F&xref=', 
          headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0'}
)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
inp = soup.find('input', {'name': 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'})
val_inp = inp.get('value')
print("Valor = {}".format(val_inp))
```

Após executar, o programa imprime:

```
Valor = tnRToqAGFLH7gsc6TEbGdv30DABebPYFcNf9WnZvsv6xoLmum3hhi3Y3ZUcnVn1a
```